# displaying pdf in iframe PHP

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, pdf, web-applications

i am creating a javascript function that displays pdf files stored in mysql database

```
code:
<iframe id="myFrame" style="display:none" width="500" height="300"></iframe>
<input type="button" value="Open PDF" onclick = "openPdf()"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
function openPdf()
{
var omyFrame = document.getElementById("myFrame");
omyFrame.style.display="block";
omyFrame.src = "myFile.pdf";
}
</script>
```

However, I have to spicify the location of the file in my drive, so is there any way to path the location of the file in the database depening on the id of the file?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set up a web service, accept pdf file name, return pdf file content. Then set iframe.src to this service url with pdf name

Answer (score 0):

You can use the JSON format to store the file's `relative path` with any extra description as follows

```
 ["thisId","/path/to/the/file/thisFile.pdf"]
```

Use `json_decode()` to get each parameter from the above.

Other way you can do is deploy another column in your mysql that keeps a track of id. But if it is trivial and not used for major normalization, then I suggest you use jSON